# What's the default encoding for Sha1 in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, character-encoding, python-2.x

I have an Api code from Python 2 is as below:

```
dataStr = request.POST['data']
data = json.loads(dataStr)
key_string = data.get('key')
seed = data.get('seed')
guid = data.get('guid')

sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
yesStr = seed + 'yes' + key_string + 'ke.yp.ad' + guid
sha1.update(yesStr)
yesValue = sha1.hexdigest()
resp = {
            'data': yesValue,
            'place_id': str(record.GroupNumber)
        }
return HttpResponse(resp)
```

now I am upgrading it to python 3, but sha1.update must use an encoded string. but I don't know what the encoding format was.  so far I tried

```
sha1.udpate(yesStr.encode("utf-8"))
sha1.udpate(yesStr.encode("ascii"))
```

but none of them is matching the old string. Can anyone help?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured this out with my friend's help.  The default encoding for Python 2 is 'latin1'.  So what I did to fix the problem is to change

```
sha1.update(yesStr)
```

to:

```
sha1.update(yesStr.encode('latin1'))
```

and it worked in python 3.